# Base Series scaling for BIRT radar chart

Tags: birt, scaling, radar-chart

I am trying to set different scales for the base series in a radar(spider) chart using BIRT. Is that possible? If yes, how is it done? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
ChartWithoutAxes cwoaSpider = ChartWithoutAxesImpl.create( );
    cwoaSpider.setDimension( ChartDimension.TWO_DIMENSIONAL_LITERAL );
    cwoaSpider.setType(TYPE_LITERAL);
    cwoaSpider.setSubType( "Spider Radar Chart" );
/**...**/

    //Data Set
    String[] objAxesArray = objAxesNames.toArray(new String[objAxesNames.size()]);
    TextDataSet categoryValues = TextDataSetImpl.create( objAxesArray );

    // Base Series
    Series seCategory = SeriesImpl.create( );
    seCategory.setDataSet( categoryValues ); //!!! Here I want for each category a different scale

    SeriesDefinition sd = SeriesDefinitionImpl.create( );
    sd.getSeriesPalette( ).shift( 0 );
    sd.getSeries( ).add( seCategory );

    // Orthogonal Series
    for (int index = 0; index < solutionsList.size(); index ++){
        NumberDataSet seriesObjValues = NumberDataSetImpl.create(solObjValuesMap.get(solutionsList.get(index).getLabel()));
        RadarSeries seRadar = RadarSeriesImpl.create( );
        seRadar.setDataSet( seriesObjValues );
        seRadar.setSeriesIdentifier( solutionsList.get(index).getLabel() ); 
        seRadar.getLabel( ).setVisible( true );
        seRadar.setConnectEndpoints(true);
        seRadar.setFillPolys(true);

        SeriesDefinition sdObj = SeriesDefinitionImpl.create( );
        sd.getSeriesDefinitions( ).add( sdObj);
        sdObj.getSeries( ).add( seRadar );  
    }
    cwoaSpider.getSeriesDefinitions( ).add( sd );
```